# Can the impulse-momentum and work-energy principles be combined?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, momentum, work, collision

I was curious if the work-energy and impulse-momentum principles be combined where the common factor is average Force.

Work Energy: $F_{avg} \times d = 0.5m(v_f-v_0)^2$
Impulse Momentum: $F_{avg} \times t = m(v_f-v_0)$

Combining them you get $0.5tm(v_f-v_0)^2 = dm(v_f-v_0)$. Masses cancel each other leaving: $0.5t(v_f-v_0)^2 = d(v_f-v_0)$. This further reduces to $0.5t(v_f-v_0)=d$ or $(v_f-v_0)=\frac{2d}{t}$.

But wouldnt $v$ be equal to $\frac{d}{t}$ and not $v=\frac{2d}{t}$.

Comment: Double check your first Work Energy equation.

Comment: Another mistake is setting $v=v_f-v_0$. Actually, $\tfrac{d}{t}=v_{avg}=\tfrac{v_0+v_f}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

So yes, you *can* do this. It is seen to more fully be valid using techniques that we call "vectors" and "calculus", where one discovers that Newton's law $\sum_i \vec F_i = m \vec a = m \frac{d\vec v}{dt}$ actually implies, if you define the "power exerted by a force $\vec F_i$" as $P_i = \vec F_i\cdot\vec v$, that $$\sum_i P_i = \sum_i \vec F_i \cdot \vec v = \left(\sum_i ~\vec F_i\right) \cdot \vec v = m~\frac{d\vec v}{dt}\cdot \vec v = \frac12 m \frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec v\cdot\vec v\right) = \frac{dK}{dt},$$where $K = \frac12 m v^2$ and we're assuming that the mass is not changing over time.

That's probably a bit over your head at this stage, but the important thing is, *yes*, we can do this explicitly using *only* algebra for the special case of one constant force in the direction of motion.

In this case one has two times $t_0, t_1$ that one is interested in, two velocities $v_0, v_1$, and two positions, $x_0, x_1,$ and one acceleration. For constant accelerations, the average velocity can be expressed in two ways, $$v_\text{avg} = \frac{v_1 + v_0}{2} = \frac{x_1 - x_0}{t_1-t_0},$$but we also know that the acceleration is the change in velocity over change in time, $$a = \frac{v_1 - v_0}{t_1 - t_0}.$$
We can use these both to solve for and eliminate the time difference $t_1 - t_0$ as$$t_1 - t_0 = \frac{v_1 - v_0}{a},$$so our earlier expression says:$$\frac{v_1 + v_0}{2} = a~\frac{x_1 - x_0}{v_1 - v_0}.$$Multiplying through by $v_1 - v_0$ on both sides the left hand side is a classic expression for factoring the difference of squares: if you FOIL it out you will find that $(a + b)(a - b) = a^2 +ab - ab - b^2=a^2-b^2.$

Similarly here you will end up finding, $$\frac12 \big(v_1^2 - v_0^2\big) = a~(x_1 - x_0).$$Multiplying through by the mass and defining $K = \frac12 m~v^2$ one finds that $F=ma$ becomes $$K_1 - K_0 = F ~(x_1 - x_0).$$

Answer (score 0):

Correction:

Work Energy is $F_{avg} \times d = \frac12 m(v_f^2-v_0^2)$

Impulse Momentum: $F_{avg} \times t = m(v_f−v_0)$

Which becomes,
$md(v_f-v_0)=\frac12 mt(v_f^2-v_0^2)$
masses cancel --->
$d(v_f-v_0)=\frac12 t(v_f^2-v_0^2)$

For a splat event where $v_f=0$, we get $-dv_0=-\frac12tv_0^2$

which simplifies to $v_0=2d/t$.

So, first question is can the two principles be combined in the first place as i've done. And then the second question is, if does everything reduce to $v_0=2d/t$ -- assuming a "splat" condition.

Comment: As I wrote in my comment, $v_{avg}=\tfrac{v_0+v_f}{2}$. If you set $v_f=0$, this reduces to $v_{avg}=\tfrac{v_0}{2}$ which is exactly what you got for $\tfrac{d}{t}$!

Comment: If i dont care about v_avg, does everything else make sense? (ie the relationship between work distance (d), impulse time (t), and the starting velocity (v0)?

Comment: Yes, and the explanation why it does exactly involves $v_{avg}$. ;)